# How to implement autocomplete search from google in rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, google-search

I am newbie in rails ,i don't know how implement this feature in application . please suggest me any basic idea.

if any user create a book ->

1) Book name should be auto suggested like Google search(if user enter a name , it should be automatically search correct name from Google and suggest to user ).

2) Author name also be auto suggested like Google Search(if user enter a name , it should be automatically search correct name from Google and suggest to user ).

Book Model has following attributes .

```
> Book.new 
 =>Book(id: integer, user_id: integer, author: string, name: string, published_at: datetime)
```

Comment: Here is a good writeup: http://www.lugolabs.com/articles/20-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks for reply @ruby_newbie , but this article is for searching  result from books(your local database). i am thinking about search suggestion from Google whatever user input here , we have to take results from Google search(perhaps by using 'Google search api' that provide search suggestions in json format )